# The tint of my navigation bar changes automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have a custom button on my navigation bar and I had change the tint color of my navigation bar with `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`

[image]

When this button make the action, all navigation bar returns to blue color

[image]

How I can fix it?

Comment: what type is your button ?

Comment: A custom button with `let shareButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Button"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "Function")`

Comment: do you perform any UI changes in "Function" method ?

Comment: No, "Function" presents a View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make navigation bar as attributed as follows

Swift3.0 Code:

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]